# Touchscreen windows logon setup

Tags: windows-7, login, touchscreen, login-screen

I am installing a new TouchScreen in an industrial Kitchen. Its a cool machine, heat/cold resistant.
It uses Windows 7.

Here is the user setup I've made:

ItAdmin (Administrator account, with password)
KitchenTouch (Standarduser, no password)

The touchscreen is not suppose to have a keyboard attached.
It has to be able to function just with the touchscreen.
there is a virtual keyboard you can load in windows that you can use as a keyboard replacement.

Now here is the issue:

When I boot the computer it says "press CTRL+ALT+DELETE" to logon. When I do that I can click on "KitchenTouch" and it logs on with no password. But I need it to 'not' ask about the CTRL+ALT+DELETE
I need it to just select that user and login, as obviously the virtual keyboard doesn't function from the login menu, so unless they have a physical keyboard attached they won't be able to login.

How do I setup the machine so it just selects this specific user and login, no questions asked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by "disabling" the user login process.  There's a good summary on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/coolstuff/Tip-Auto-Login-Your-Windows-7-User-Account)
.  I certainly wouldn't recommend this for any machine that's connected to a network, however, as it's a huge security risk.

Comment: hey BBklage, thx for the answer, I will try and follow the guide you linked.
Can you tell me why its supposedly a huge security risk?
Lets assume I want them to be able to just login with no password.
Is there any difference if they have to click 'login' themselves or it just does it automatically?

Comment: It's probably less of a risk in the scenario you're proposing.  However, in general removing the login process allows anyone that can get access to that computer (either remotely or physically) has full access to login and immediately gains any access rights your default user has access to without having to make any effort at all.  If you did that on a laptop, for example, someone steals your laptop and they can get at anything on it without trying.  And if that laptop is connected to your wireless network, they gain easy access to that, and so on.  It makes things much easier, thus a risk.

Comment: Theoretically I need the Security to be pretty good this machine is on the Domain, I'm working for a big union so of course we have lots of stuff marked 'secret'.
The machine is part of the domain. 
But the standard user I have created is a local user, with no admin rights.

I followed the guide and it starts up correctly in the standard user, what concerned me to watch though was when I checked the 'don't check for login and password' it automatically unchecks it for all acounts.. also the admin account.

Does that mean they can avoid the password I placed on the local admin account?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I believe that only controls the automatic login  when you initially log in to Windows for the local account you set up.  I don't believe it should allow someone to access the domain IDs without passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup the auto-login:

1. Click on **Start** and then enter the following command in the search box: `netplwiz`
2. In the Users tab, **uncheck** the box next to "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer".
3. Click on **Apply**
4. When the "Automatically Log On" dialog appears, enter the user name you wish to automatically login to Windows 7 with (KitchenTouch in your case), and click **OK**.